# Couchbase server from CouchbaseLite

Tags: node.js, couchbase, couchbase-lite

Is it possible to query the server database from Couchbase Lite. I know there is a REST API that does what I'm looking for but I'm wondering if the Node.js API supports this feature.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, the Sync Gateway REST interface is the only method of querying at the server when you're using Couchbase Lite and Sync Gateway.